# Printing from C# and having text auto centered

Tags: c#, printing

I have built a form that populates text boxes from a data grid, and I am now trying to have the text centered when it goes to print. I know here I have everything sitting on the left hand side, but is there a way to get all text centered while I keep my images where they have been defined? The text will vary in length depending on the selected item, but I need it to be centered despite the length.

```
private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox.Image, 62, 73, 103, 120);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cardLicenseTypeTextBox.Text, 
        new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new RectangleF(0, 21, 197, 20));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cardMemberNameTextBox.Text, 
        new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new RectangleF(0, 242, 197, 20));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cardAssociationTextBox.Text, 
        new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new RectangleF(0, 260, 197, 20));

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(cardMemberNumberPictureBox.Image, 6, 281, 197, 21);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(cardMemberNumberTextBox.Text, 
        new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new RectangleF(0, 309, 197, 20));
}
```

Comment: You need to use `e.Graphics` to measure the string, and adjust its position accordingly.

Comment: You do not need to create a new unique font object each time and when you do, dispose of it

Comment: Investigate the `DrawString` parameter [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Drawing_PointF_System_Drawing_StringFormat_).

Comment: @RonBeyer I learned how to do that in an actual Typing class years ago! On an actual typewriter LOL.